# Insert after jquery

Tags: jquery, insert, datatables

Hi im trying to render datatables after intialisation and add a new row for a link

this is a part of my code an the "insert after" seems not to be working.

```
   $('#table thead tr').each(function() {
    nCloneTh.insertAfter(this.childNodes[5]);
});
```

can anybody help me? I want to insert the nCloneTh(th element) after my 5th column.

thx for help

my whole code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');

nCloneTh.innerHTML = '<img src="style/img/icon_trash.png" id="imglink" title="Entfernen" class="center">';

$('#table thead tr').each(function() {
    nCloneTh.insertAfter(this.childNodes[5]);
});

$('#table tbody tr').each(function() {
    nCloneTd.insertAfter(this.childNodes[5]);
});

$('#table tfoot th').each(function() {
    nCloneTh.insertAfter(this.childNodes[5]);
});

dataTable = $('#table').dataTable({
    'bProcessing':true,
    'bServerSide':true,
    'sAjaxSource':'feedback.php',
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "language/dataTables.german.txt"
    },'aoColumnDefs':[{'bSearchable': false, 'bVisible':false, 'aTargets':[0]},
        {'bSortable': false, 'aTargets':[5]},
        { 'fnRender': function(o,val){return '<a>tss</a>';}, 'aTargets': [ 6]}
    ]
});

dataTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
dataTable.fnDraw(false);
```

});

Comment: You want to add a new row or a new column? Looks like a new column. Will each row have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are 0-indexed, so you're trying to insert after the **sixth** `<th>` in your sample. Also, I noticed that `nCloneTh` is a DOM element, not a jQuery element. Try the following:

```
$('#table thead tr').each(function() {  
    $(nCloneTh).insertAfter($(this).children('th')[4]);
});
```

Comment: I just noticed that `nCloneTh` is a node, not a jQuery object. See my updated answer.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'insertAfter'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20773/discussion-between-benm-and-jannis-hanke)

Answer (score 1):

nCloneTh needs to be wrapped in a jQuery object in order to use inserAfter, like so:

```
var nCloneTh = $('<th></th>');
```

Here is an example of what you may be trying to accomplish -
http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/d3bLp/

Answer (score 1):

You can use aoColumns in the datatable initialization to add the extra column.  Use a `null` for each of your existing columns, then define your additional column using the mRender function.

```
dataTable = $('#table').dataTable({
    'bProcessing':true,
    'bServerSide':true,
    'sAjaxSource':'feedback.php',
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "language/dataTables.german.txt"
    },
    'aoColumnDefs':[
        {'bSearchable': false, 'bVisible':false, 'aTargets':[0]},
        {'bSortable': false, 'aTargets':[5]},
        { 'fnRender': function(o,val){return '<a>tss</a>';}, 'aTargets': [ 6]}
    ],
    aoColumns: [ null,
                 null,
                 null,
      { "sName": "ID",
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bSortable": false,
        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
           return "<img src='style/img/icon_trash.png' id='imglink' title='Entfernen'" +
                  " class='center'>";
        }
      }
    ]
});
```

http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns